# SPARQL: Exclude double resources in COUNT

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, turtle-rdf

I am trying to write a SPARQL query that only counts the number of dutch politicians for each university. How ever, for each dbo:almaMater there is for some politicians one extra resource (their major, dbr:Sociology for example). This is also reflected in the COUNT. For example. I get count 49 for Leiden University where this should be only 42. Any idea how I can resolve this? I've tried FILTER NOT EXISTS and MINUS but both do nothing to the count. Thank you.

My query:

```
SELECT distinct  ?education (COUNT(?education) AS ?edu_count) 
WHERE { ?name <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
        ?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Netherlands>.
        ?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/party> ?party.
        ?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/almaMater> ?education.
        ?education <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Public_university>.

        
} GROUP BY ?education 
ORDER BY DESC(?edu_count)
```

Comment: Instead of `?name dbo:party ?party`, try `filter exists { ?name dbo:party ?party }`. P.S. Why [tag:sql]?

Comment: @stanislavKralin thanks so much, didn't know we could use filter like that. With regards to sql, that's a mistake I'll remove it.

Comment: The correct way would be to count the ?name variable and use a distinct per group. It's also meaningless to call distinct when using group by. It should be `SELECT ?education (COUNT(DISTINCT ?name) AS ?cnt)`

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised query, based on comments, with extra whitespace for clarity. [Query in form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Feducation%0D%0A+++++++%28+COUNT+%28+DISTINCT+%3Fname+%29+AS+%3Fcnt+%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthPlace%3E++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNetherlands%3E+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fparty%3E+++++++++++++++%3Fparty+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FalmaMater%3E+++++++++++%3Feducation+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Feducation+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype%3E++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPublic_university%3E+.%0D%0A++++++%7D+%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Feducation+%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC+%28+%3Fcnt+%29+%0D%0A+++++++++ASC+%28+%3Feducation+%29%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+), and [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Feducation%0D%0A+++++++%28+COUNT+%28+DISTINCT+%3Fname+%29+AS+%3Fcnt+%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthPlace%3E++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FNetherlands%3E+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fparty%3E+++++++++++++++%3Fparty+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Fname++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FalmaMater%3E+++++++++++%3Feducation+.%0D%0A++++++++%3Feducation+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype%3E++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPublic_university%3E+.%0D%0A++++++%7D+%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Feducation+%0D%0AORDER+BY+DESC+%28+%3Fcnt+%29+%0D%0A+++++++++ASC+%28+%3Feducation+%29%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) --

```
SELECT                               ?education
       ( COUNT ( DISTINCT ?name ) AS ?cnt )
WHERE { ?name      <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
        ?name      <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>          <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Netherlands> .
        ?name      <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/party>               ?party .
        ?name      <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/almaMater>           ?education .
        ?education <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type>                <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Public_university> .
      } 
GROUP BY ?education 
ORDER BY DESC ( ?cnt ) 
         ASC ( ?education )
```